# SQL Combining Two Totally seperate tables to one

Tags: sql

I am VERY new to SQL and self taught.  I have two SQL that I stuggled through but got working.  Now I need to combine them into one and I'm lost.

```
SELECT
    s.lastfirst,
    s.student_number,
    SUM(tr.howmany) 
FROM
    students s 
JOIN 
    truancies tr ON s.id = tr.studentid 
WHERE
    s.enroll_status = 0 AND
    s.schoolid = ~(curschoolid)
GROUP BY
    s.lastfirst, s.student_number 
HAVING
    SUM(tr.howmany) > 0
ORDER BY
    s.lastfirst
```

And this table:

```
SELECT 
    S.DCID as DCID,
    S.LASTFIRST as LASTFIRST,
    S.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_NUMBER,
    S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE as FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE,
    CASE 
       WHEN S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED IS NULL 
          THEN '0' 
          ELSE S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED 
    END AS FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED,
    S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT as FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT,
    CASE
       WHEN S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED IS NULL 
          THEN S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE * S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT
          ELSE ((S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE - S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED) * S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT) 
    END as Balance_Due
FROM
    STUDENTS S, U_STUDENTSUSERFIELDS S2 
WHERE
    S.DCID = S2.STUDENTSDCID AND
    s.enroll_status = 0 AND
    s.schoolid = ~(curschoolid) AND 
    (((S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE - S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED) * S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT) > 0 OR
    ((S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE - S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_COMPLETED) * S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_BUYOUT) IS NULL) AND
    S2.FC_SRVC_HRS_DUE >.1
ORDER BY
    s.lastfirst
```

What I am really looking for are the totals of both of these. I want the `SUM(tr.howmany)` from the first table and the balance due of the second BUT I need the filters that are in there. This would be sorted by student. I hope I am making sense. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Give your current and expected result.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can join together 2 separate SQL select statements:

```
Eg:
Select A.id, A.value, B.value
From   (select id, count(*) as value from TableA ...) AS A
join   (select id, sum(field) as value from TableB ...) AS B
on   A.id = B.id
order by A.id
```

As long as you have a common field to join on this would work.  In your case the student_number looks like a good candidate.  You will have to do the ordering outside of your subqueries.